# How to send attachment with phpmailer in yii framweork from function?

Tags: php, email, yii, email-attachments

> I am using Yii framwework and phpmailer to send mail to particular
> user.My mail function is working properly but i am stuck in attchment
> part as i am generating pdf from one function.

Having function to generate pdf data will be dynamic here:

```
public function generatePdf()
{
   $html = '';
   $html .= '<div></div>'; //and same like this all html part.
   echo $html;
  //mpdf stuff will come here.
      $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);  //             
      $mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2); 
      $mpdf->Output($path.$file_name, "F");
}
```

This function is working properly to generate pdf. But Now i want to use this same function to send attachment with Mail.I dont know how to achieve this.Please help me in this.

I am having another function to send Mail :

```
public function sentMail(){
   $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;

    $mail->Username = GUSER;  
    $mail->Password = GPWD;           
    $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Message sent!';
        return true;
    }  // demo code
}
```

How to use that generatePdf function inside my sentMail() as a attachment.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function generatePdf()
{
   $html = '';
   $html .= '<div></div>'; //and same like this all html part.
   echo $html;
  //mpdf stuff will come here.
      $mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet,1);  //             
      $mpdf->WriteHTML($html,2); 
      $mpdf->Output($path.$file_name, "F");
      return $path.$file_name;
}



public function sentMail(){
    $mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false;
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;    
    $mail->Username = GUSER;  
    $mail->Password = GPWD;           
    $mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    //If you know path then use this
    #$mail->addAttachment("uploads/".$file_name); //Here add the proper path
    
    //If you want to attach the use below, 
    //If you write this in single class then call with $this->generatePdf()
    $mail->addAttachment(generatePdf());

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
        return false;
    } else {
        $error = 'Message sent!';
        return true;
    }  // demo code
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. But i am not storing my pdf anywhere. its dynamically created and i have to set that attachment.

Comment: @amitsutar, Please check i  updated code this will helpful